# Reducing dependencies for a .NET Standard class library?

Tags: nuget, .net-standard

I have converted some of my class libraries to .NET Standard with Visual Studio 2017.

This was easy, add a .NET Standard class library project in place of the original project and add all the files in there. The .csproj file even looks like a nuspec file now with package information and such. Inside the project options there was a checkbox for "Generate NuGet package on build", which I checked. Easy peasy.

However, .NET Framework consumers of my class library now gets a ton of dependencies, I counted at least 20 other nuget packages that were added, most of which was completely unecessary for my library. In other words, was "easy peasy **too** easy?"

Is this just a byproduct of me using .NET Standard as the *only* build output and I should add back a .NET Framework library as well?

Packages such as the following will be added to a project that consumes my library, even though they are completely unnecessary:

- System.Security.Cryptography.*
- System.Xml.*
- System.IO.*

etc. there's plenty of packages being added. My library does "glorified" array analysis and doesn't require much at all.

The Visual Studio project is configured to target .NET Standard 1.0 and the only reference visible is the "NETStandardLibrary" so it's not like I added all of those myself.

I've inspected the package and it doesn't seem to list all of those either.

Can I add only the packages I need and still target .NET Standard 1.0?

My class library is open source here: https://github.com/lassevk/DiffLib
The nuget package is here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/difflib/2017.4.24.2347

Comment: I was particularly happy with how easy it was to produce a nuget package and I'm afraid that if I go back to multiple build outputs I need to go back to maintaining the nuspec and build system myself instead of just letting Visual Studio deal with it now that it can.

Comment: What you can't easily see are the packages that the packages you actually use need to get their job done.  The .NETCore team admitted last week that breaking up corefx like that was a mistake and caused a lot more problems than it solved.  It will be fixed soon with the release of v2.0, hopefully after that stabilizes this will be but a bad memory soon enough.

Comment: OK, so judging by the [platform support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) I probably need to include both 2.0 and 1.0 as possible targets, to at least help people with newer runtimes. I'm reluctant to just upgrade to 2.0 and ditch 1.6 though since the matrix contains more framework versions supported by 1.0. That seems doable since I know I can list multiple standard version targets by manually "hacking" the project file. Thanks.

Comment: Though if I could say that I only needed 1 or 2 of those packages, and that would include a couple more because of their dependencies that would also be nice but I guess things like this will only be fixed by going to 2.0, 1.x is thus not going to become better in this regard, is that what you're saying? If so, please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite a complex situation at the moment:

> Can I add only the packages I need and still target .NET Standard 1.0?

Yes you can do it, but this is no longer recommended. In essence, `.NET Standard` is a specification that is made up of the packages referencing it. The supported way is to reference `NETStandard.Library` since it guarantees to bring you all needed compilation references and logic that you need in order to build correctly.

Beginning with the upcoming `netstandard2.0`, `NETStandard.Library` will be a flat package without dependencies and the individual packages will be removed from the dependency tree if your project or any other project references them. Also, `NETStandard.Library` will not be published as a dependency - so if you build a `netstandard2.0` library, the resulting NuGet package will have no dependencies. (`NETStandard.Library.NETFramework` is required to be installed when using it in .net framework projects - NuGet is supposed to do this automatically).

That being said, if you really want to do it, you can set

```
<DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
```

in the `csproj` file and then add items like `<PackageReference Include="System.[Something]" Version="4.3.0" />` for everything you need.

Comment: > "Also, NETStandard.Library will not be published as a dependency - so if you build a netstandard2.0 library, the resulting NuGet package will have no dependencies." - I am confused. Have just packed a library targeting netstandard 2 and this is the nuspec that is produced: 
 <dependencies>
     
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>

Comment: looks like you built with old tooling - maybe 1.0.* or a preview version using project.json? there weren't any safeguards in place in those versions.

Comment: make sure `dotnet --version` on a command line inside the project directory shows at least `2.0.0` when you build for .net standard 2.0

Comment: Thanks. I updated various nuget packages (including Xamarin.Forms) - did another Pack and low and behold it now works :-)